# Transform Hilbert's Hotel in a sequential moving Guests

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, infinity

Example 1:
Hilbert's Hotel is described in Wikipedia as following:
Suppose a new guest arrives and wishes to be accommodated in the hotel. We can (simultaneously) move the guest currently in room 1 to room 2, the guest currently in room 2 to room 3, and so on, moving every guest from his current room n to room n+1. After this, room 1 is empty and the new guest can be moved into that room.

Example 2:
Transforming it to a sequential moving Hotel:
New guest arrives.

Step 1: guest 2 moves out room 2.

Step 2: guest 1 moves in room 2.

Step 3: guest 3 moves out room 3.

Step 4: guest 2 moves in room 3.

...

In the thought experiment example 2, you could describe it like this:
guest 1 moves in 60 seconds, guest 2 in 30 seconds, guest 3 in 15 seconds and so on. After 2 minutes every guest moved from his current room to room n+1.

In example 1 an infinite amount of guests moved simultaneously. In example 2, all guest moved after 2 minutes.

What are the reason, why you think example 1 / example 2 is more faithful or both same faithful?

Comment: I'm not sure what this is asking - what does "mathematically like" mean in this context? Of course there are similarities and differences between the two phrasings (in particular, the second is less faithful to the *mathematical* observation motivating the "story," namely that there is a non-surjective injection from $\mathbb{N}$ to itself).

Comment: An infinite hotel does not exist in reality anyway. So we can assume that the guest all move simultaneously to avoid the issue that the procedure takes infinite long which would however not matter much, since this is as said anyway only a theoretical visualization of the surprises that occur in infinite sets and how to deal with them.

Comment: An infinite sequence of moves can be done in $2$ minutes if the $n$th move takes $2^{-n}$ minute.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Aren’t example 1 and 2 a non-surjective injection from ℕ (guests) to ℕ(rooms)? In both, never two guests send in one room (injective) and in both room 1 ends up empty (non-surjective).

Answer (score -2):

Let’s say every guest moves simultaneously his current room to room n+1. First I order all guests to stay out their rooms. Guest 1 stays before room 1, guest 2 before room 2 and so on. Then I will imagine what could happen. Guest 1 will move to room 2 and force guest 2 to move out his room. Guest 1 will move into room 2. Guest 2 has no room. Guest 2 will move to room 3 and force guest 3 to move out his room. Guest 3 hast no room and so on. The speed of imagination has no limit. For the first step my brain needed 1 minute, the second step could be done in 30 seconds. The third step in 15 and fourth in only 7.5. After two minutes, I caught every single step in my imagination. Now I let all infinite guests move simultaneously. For me my imagination should go the same way as moving all guests simultaneously, at least I did not find a reason why not. Case closed, question can be deleted if wanted. I am also fine with justifying me wrong.
Have a nice day.